# ASIFormDataRequest Uploading file

Tags: cocoa, xcode, file-upload, ios4

Good Day!

i am using ASIFormDataRequest to upload file, now everthing works but the upload of file does not work. it does nothing, but other than that it works fine, i dont understand the reason, can you please help me out. here is my calling code.

```
[self setRequest:[ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost:8888/registerUserASI.php"]]];
[request setPostValue:strDeviceID forKey:@"userDeviceId"];
[request setPostValue:strCurrentDate forKey:@"userDateTime"];

NSData *data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image.image);
[request setData:[[data base64Encoding] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] forKey:@"userfile"];
```

btw i have also tried the SetData and AddData methods of this request as well. but same results.

The Php code is Working fine with any file upload but not this one, Can somebody help me out.

It might be php code issue that i am not properly handling for this specific request. but with other methods the uploading is working, but i want to work with this.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not converting space to its %20 just because of that it was not working.

Answer (score 0):

you say it does nothing. Did you start your request:

```
[request startSynchronous];
```

or

```
[request startAsynchronous];
```

I mostly use the async way, cause it does not freeze any UI. Then you have also to set the delegate of the request, so you also receive callbacks on success or fail of the request.